# Pytest - How to pass defaults while testing

Tags: python, parameters, pytest, default

Suppose that I have a function as follows

```
def add_vals(a, b=1, c=2):
    result = a + b + c
    return result
```

Let the test data be as follows

```
test_data = [(1, 2, 3), (6),
(2, ,4), (7)
]
```

For the second test I want the function to use default value for `b` i.e.  `b=1` How can I do that?

To test I am using the following function.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("inp,expected", testdata)
def test_add_vals(inp, expected):
    res = historical_returns(*inp)

    assert res == expected
```

**Edit**

Based on the suggestion using `**kwargs` to pass default parameters. Having syntax issue can't figure out the error. Below is the code

```
def add_vals(a, b=1, c=2):
    result = a + b + c
    return result


testdata = [(1, 'b'=9, 12),
            (2, 'c'=5, 8)
            ]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("args, kwargs, expected", testdata)
def test_add_vals(args, kwargs, expected):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        res = add_vals(*args, key=value)

    assert res == expected
```

Below is the error

```
E       testdata = [((1), ('b' = 1), (6)),
E                              ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use args _and_ kwargs?

Comment: Can't really get my head around that idea. Can you post an answer?

Comment: Re: syntax error. You need to pass in a `dict`. `("b"=1)` is invalid syntax for a `dict`. Instead, use `{"b":1}` or `dict(b=1)`. The whole line would be: `testdata = [([1], {'b':9}, 12),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested, you can use a combination of a list or arguments (`args`) and a dict of keyword arguments (`kwargs`) like this:

```py
import pytest


def add_vals(a, b=1, c=2):
    result = a + b + c
    return result


testdata = [([1], {"b": 9}, 12),
            ([2], {"c": 5}, 8),
            ([0, 1, 2], {}, 3),
            ([], {"c": 3, "b": -3, "a": 0}, 0)
            ]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("args, kwargs, expected", testdata)
def test_add_vals(args, kwargs, expected):
    res = add_vals(*args, **kwargs)
    assert res == expected
```

Further reading: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html